# POSTGIS raster/Java with GDAL bindings - Load byte array in Gdal Dataset Object

Tags: postgis, gdal

I would like to load a raster as  java.awt.image.BufferedImage (or equivalent class that would allow to perform some display) out of my PostGIS database. My Raster is inDb (loaded with raster2pgsql)

I already created a proper DAO to "connect" the Postgis database and my Java package. 
So far, I managed to import an display tiles from my raster using POSTGIS ST_AsPNG queries as presented in the code extract below.

```
public BufferedImage test_raster() {

    byte[] content = null;
    Dataset dattaset = null;

    try {

        ResultSet result = this .connect
                                .createStatement(
                                            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
                                                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE
                                         ).executeQuery(
             "SELECT ST_AsPNG(rast) as tmp FROM bath50m  WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((50 50, 50 0, 0 0, 0 50, 50 50)))',4326))"
                                         );
        while(result.next()){
            if (result.absolute(result.getRow())){

            content = result.getBytes("tmp"); 
                ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bis);

            }
        }   

    } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return image;
}
```

That is interresting but I'd like to keep the geographic metadata that are embedded with the raster.

I decided to give a try to extract tiles using the POSTGIS ST_AsGdalRaster so metadata would be passed along with the image. I properly compile GDAL to get the java bindings and set PATH so that I can use it (I tried succesfully the [Nasa Worldwind GDALtest.java](http://worldwind31.arc.nasa.gov/svn/tags/1.5.1/GDAL/GDAL-1.7.2/swig/java/apps/GDALtest.java))

According to the doc, it returns the raster tile in the designated GDAL Raster format. Raster formats are one of those supported by your compiled library. Use ST_GDALRasters() to get a list of formats supported by your library.

Actually ST_AsGdalRaster returns a bytes array that I can't cast to the Gdal Dataset type. My intention was to adapt the openfile method from the GDALtest.java  to pass byte array or whatever I could.

I am not sure where I am going with that. I know I am doing something wrong but I miss support/experience to realize it.

Any help would be welcome.

Thanks for reading me

edit: I realize I need to clarify meaning. I try to use the GDALDataset Class with a byte array as input. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking more carefully at the GDAL reference and stepped into that  [IT-usenet thread](http://en.it-usenet.org/thread/12180/2385/), I finally manage to create a proper Gdaldataset from an in-memory byte array.

That operation requires to load all gdal drivers to get access to the supported Gdal file format. Then you need and to load it in a virtual file, allowed by the gdal FileFromMemBuffer function.

gdal.AllRegister();

//link a virtual file to your byte stream

gdal.FileFromMemBuffer("/vsimem/tiffinmem", content);

//open the dataset as it was a file using the gdal Open function

Dataset dataset = gdal.Open("/vsimem/tiffinmem");

All specific geographic metadatas an more are then conveniently accessible.

Cheers!